# score in pong game. How to update the score in a pong game?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

ok so i'm creating the game pong and i'm currently setting up the score.There is a small bug I'm unable to fix. The code I tried was `R2Score = R2Score + 1` for it to add a point every time it gets out of the screen. It is telling me there's an error with this code and i'm under how to fix it. Also as it is going to get out of the screen the ball slows down which I'm confused on why that could also be happening.

ERROR:

> ```
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "/Users/name/Documents/PongGame.py", line 130, in <module>
>    R2Score = R2Score + 1
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'pygame.Surface' and 'int'
> ```

```
# import the necessary modules
import pygame
import sys
import time

#initialize pygame
pygame.init()
screenSize=(700,500)
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((screenSize), 0)

# set the caption for the screen
pygame.display.set_caption("Pong Game")

# define colours you will be using
WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREEN = (0,255,0)
RED = (255,0,0)
BLUE = (0,0,255)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
YELLOW = (255,255,0)

# set the size for the surface (screen)
screen_h = screen.get_height()
screen_w = screen.get_width()
cx = int(screen_w/2)
cy = int(screen_h/2)

#initialize variables for player
#variables for first rectangle
R1x = 660
R1y = 300
R1w = 10
R1h = 132

R1dx = 0
R1dy = 0
R1_score = 0

#variables for second rectangle
R2x = 10
R2y = 2
R2w = 10
R2h = 132

R2dx = 0
R2dy = 0
R2_score = 0

#ball variables
bx = cx
by = cy
dby = 3
dbx = 3
br = 5
cy =  screen.get_height()/2
cx =  screen.get_width()/2

# variable for scores
R1_score = 0
R2_score = 0

playerRect = pygame.Rect(R1x, R1y, R1w, R1h)
playerRect2 = pygame.Rect(R2x, R2y, R2w, R2h)
ballRect = pygame.Rect (cx,cy,30,30)

#speed
speed = 3

fontsize = 50
fontScore = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)
fontScore = pygame.font.SysFont('arial', 50)

R1Score = fontScore.render(str(R1_score), True, (WHITE))
R2Score = fontScore.render(str(R2_score), True, (WHITE))

# speed of object "clock"
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

# set main loop to True so it will run
main = True
# main loop
while main:
    for event in pygame.event.get(): # check for any events (i.e key press, mouse click etc.)
        if event.type ==pygame.QUIT: # check to see if it was "x" at top right of screen
            main = False         # set the "main" variable to False to exit while loop
        if event.type ==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = -speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = speed
            if event.key == pygame.K_w:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = -speed
            elif event.key == pygame.K_s:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = speed
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                R1dx = 0
                R1dy = 0
            elif event.key == pygame.K_w or event.key == pygame.K_s:
                R2dx = 0
                R2dy = 0

    playerRect.y = playerRect.y + R1dy
    playerRect2.y = playerRect2.y + R2dy
    ballRect.move_ip(dbx,dby)


    R1y = R1dy + R1y
    R2y = R2dy + R2y
    bx = dbx + bx
    by = dby + by

    if R1y >= screen_h - 80 or R1y < 0:
        R1dy = 0
    if R2y >= screen_h - 80 or R2y < 0:
        R2dy = 0
    if by >= screen_h - br:
        dby = -1
    if by <= 15:
        dby = 1
    if bx >= R2x - br and by - R2y > 0 and by - R2y <100:
        dbx = -1
    if bx >= R1x - br and by - R1y > 0 and by - R1y <100:
        dbx = 1
    if bx == 1:
        R2Score = R2Score + 1
        pause = True
    if bx == 699:
        R2Score = R2Score + 1
        pause = True

    #collision of ball
    if ballRect.top <= 0:
        dby = -dby
    if ballRect.bottom >= screen_h:
        dby = -dby

    if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect2):
        dbx = -dbx
    if ballRect.colliderect(playerRect):
        dbx = -dbx

    screen.fill(BLACK)

    # draw the shapes
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(playerRect),0)
    pygame.draw.rect(screen, WHITE,(playerRect2),0)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, RED,ballRect.center,br,0)
    screen.blit(R1Score, (280,10))
    screen.blit(R2Score, (400,10))

    # we are using .flip() here,  it basically works the same as .update()
    time.sleep(0.005)
    pygame.display.flip()

# quit pygame and exit the program (i.e. close everything down)
pygame.quit()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: I'm still confused as it still doesn't add a point when the ball gets out of the screen. Also the ball is moving crazy and isn't following the back and forth.

Comment: A good Stack Overflow question shows the *shortest possible code* that demonstrates a specific problem, removing anything that isn't absolutely essential to being able to reproduce that failure. There's no reason for what you give us to be a pong game at all; it should be the shortest code that someone can run without changes to see the problem you encountered while writing your pong game, with all the game elements (not specifically related to the problem) removed / simplified away. See the [mcve] guidelines.

Comment: (Keyboard input has nothing to do with the problem; why take input? If you don't need to run for more than one frame to produce the problem, why implement movement, or code that only gets called when movement takes place? You can just set up an initial score and then *always* try to increment it by one, with no user control at all, and that should suffice).

Comment: ...as an alternate definition to the [mre] page linked above, see also the [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://ssscc.eorg) definition.

Comment: ...and insofar as you have *more than one* problem described in the same question, that's just running out-of-scope, and should be multiple questions asked one-at-a-time, each with only the shortest code that reproduces that one, narrow problem.

Comment: You need to debug your code and see where it starts doing what you don't want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

`R2Score` is a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object, so what do you expect by `R2Score = R2Score + 1`?
You can't add 1 to a `Surface`.

If you wan to increment the score, then you have to (re-)render the `Surface`. e.g.:

```py
if bx == 1:
    R1_score += 1
    R1Score = fontScore.render(str(R1_score), True, (WHITE))
```